# Cocos2d: Disable rotation display for CCSprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am creating a sprite like this:

```
CatSprite *aCat = [CatSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-Small.png"];

// add sprite to CCLayer
[self addChild:aCat];
// and then define the body and shape
cpBody *body = cpBodyNew(10.0f, cpMomentForPoly(1000.0f, num, verts, CGPointZero));

body->p = ccp(x, y);
cpSpaceAddBody(space, body);
cpShape* shape = cpPolyShapeNew(body, num, verts, CGPointZero);
shape->e = 0.5f; shape->u = 1.0f;
shape->data = aCat;
cpSpaceAddShape(space, shape);
```

I am applying physics and constraints to the body in chipmunk space. What I want is to disable the display of the body rotation, in other words when body rotate I want the sprite to stay  on 0 degree. Any ideas please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is inevitably somewhere that you are copying the rotation of the body to the sprite. Unless you are using the released-days-ago alpha preview of Cocos2D v3, CCSprites and cpBodies don't actually work together unless you write code that syncs the sprite with the body. Simply don't copy the rotation for that sprite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, no that's only what I did (the code above).

Comment: Hi slembcke I will accept your answer after testing I discovered that this line shape->data = aCat; transmits the rotation and position. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable body rotation completely, setting its inertia to `INFINITY`, e.g. `cpBodyNew(10.0f, INFINITY);`

Comment: I want the body to rotate because it should rotate but not the shape.

Comment: Which cocos2d version are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using cocos2d-iphone-1.0.1. Thanks.